# How to rename the Node running a mnesia Database

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I created a Mnesia database / Schema on machine1. The node was named mypl@machine1. I then moved all files to machine2, because machine1 broke down. Everything runs fine as long as the code is running with the name "mypl@machine1". Obviously this is somewhat confugsing, because it is now running on machine2.

If I start Erlang with the node name "mypl@machine2" the Mnesia Database appears being empty.

How do I rename the node in a Mnesia Database from machine1 to machine2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think this can be done online on a single node(anyone?), but it is possible to do via a backup/restore in addition to running two nodes and adding table copies. In the [Mnesia User's guide](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/part_frame.html) section 6.9.1 you'll find some code that uses mnesia:traverse_backup to alter the node names in the schema table (Shown below) in an mnesia backup file. The module name you should probably use is `mnesia_backup`.

With this code you'll need to:

```
%% On mypl@machine1
mnesia:backup("/path/to/mnesia.backup").
change_node_name(mnesia_backup, mypl@machine1, mypl@machine2,
                 "/path/to/mnesia.backup", "/path/to/new.mnesia.backup").
%% On mypl@machine2
mnesia:restore("/path/to/new.mnesia.backup", []).
```

I'm not sure if you need to create the schema first on `mypl@machine2`.

The change node name code from the user's guide:

```
change_node_name(Mod, From, To, Source, Target) ->
    Switch =
        fun(Node) when Node == From -> To;
           (Node) when Node == To -> throw({error, already_exists});
           (Node) -> Node
        end,
    Convert =
        fun({schema, db_nodes, Nodes}, Acc) ->
                {[{schema, db_nodes, lists:map(Switch,Nodes)}], Acc};
           ({schema, version, Version}, Acc) ->
                {[{schema, version, Version}], Acc};
           ({schema, cookie, Cookie}, Acc) ->
                {[{schema, cookie, Cookie}], Acc};
           ({schema, Tab, CreateList}, Acc) ->
                Keys = [ram_copies, disc_copies, disc_only_copies],
                OptSwitch =
                    fun({Key, Val}) ->
                            case lists:member(Key, Keys) of
                                true -> {Key, lists:map(Switch, Val)};
                                false-> {Key, Val}
                            end
                    end,
                {[{schema, Tab, lists:map(OptSwitch, CreateList)}], Acc};
           (Other, Acc) ->
                {[Other], Acc}
        end,
    mnesia:traverse_backup(Source, Mod, Target, Mod, Convert, switched).
```

Comment: I followed the steps about but failed on restoring, any suggestion?
1. backup the original database
2. change node name
3. copy the bak into another machine
4. restore the new backup file
The error message is: {aborted,{'EXIT',{aborted,{bad_commit,{missing_lock,'web_server@anothernode'}}}}}

Answer (score 2):

Workaround is migration. Just start mnesia cluster and migrate all your tables and schema to other node. Than remove from original and forgot.