# Backing up a Mnesia database with Elixir

Tags: erlang, backup, elixir, mnesia

I've got an Elixir app that uses a Mnesia database. It works fine and I can store and retrieve data no problem. I'm now looking at how to back up that database and, reading through the documentation, found that there is a `:mnesia.backup` function that should do what I want. However, when I call it, I get:

`:mnesia.backup("myfile")
{:error, {:EXIT, {:error, :function_clause}}}`

And the logs show this:

`[error] Mnesia(:nonode@nohost): ** ERROR ** Failed to abort backup. :mnesia_backup::abort_write["myfile"] -> {:badrecord, :backup}`

That line in the log is confusing as I wasn't trying to abort the backup at all.

The `:function_clause` error suggests that an invalid argument is passed somewhere so I search online to see what I should pass to the `backup` function (the Erlang docs are particularly unclear about that) and found this question that suggests it should be the name of the backup file: [what is the proper way to backup/restore a mnesia database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154414/what-is-the-proper-way-to-backup-restore-a-mnesia-database)

I had a look at the mnesia code to see if I could find anything obvious but no joy there.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

I am using Elixir 1.4.1 with Erlang/OTP 19 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a basic code example that demonstrates the problem if needed.

Comment: Try single quotes: `:mnesia.backup('myfile')`.

Comment: That works and proves I still need to get my head round the difference between binaries, strings and char lists in Elixir, thanks! Do you mind making this an answer so that I can accept it as the correct answer please?

Comment: Basically - Erlang doesn't have strings, just charlists, so using strings with Erlang's modules didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:mnesia.backup` accepts a charlist as the file name, which are written in double quotes in Erlang syntax but single quotes in Elixir. The following should work:

```
:mnesia.backup('myfile')
```

I'd highly recommend going through this [official Elixir crash course](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html) to quickly pick up Erlang syntax if you know Elixir syntax or vice versa.