# Erlang release, set node name for ./bin/XXXXX start -name nonode@nohost

Tags: erlang, mnesia, relx

I have an existing mnesia database, and now I started with proper erlang releases. I use relx.

However, the problem is that I need to be compatible with the existing mnesia database, and when that was created, the node name was nonode@nohost. I have seen that for mnesia, the node name is more than part of a directory name, i.e. it cannot be changed without using backup and restore and some processing.

I can run the release with

> bin/XXXX console -name nonode@nohost

and the database is found. However, I would like to use

> bin/XXXX start -name nonode@nohost

but then the -name is ignored. When I attach, and do node(), I get something else.

I also found the vm.args file and changed the node name to nonode@nohost there, but got

> {error_logger,{{2015,2,14},{13,25,17}},"Invalid node name: ~p~n",['nonode@nohost']}

So it seems that someone really made sure that the name cannot be nonode@nohost :-) Is my only option to do like this: [How to rename the Node running a mnesia Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463400/how-to-rename-the-node-running-a-mnesia-database)

Answer (score 0):

Usually erlang command line args are placed in a file called `vm.args`. You can find it in release directory.
Each line of this file is vm option, so in your case you need to put:

`-name nonode@nohost`

to this file.

Comment: That doesn't work, as the original poster already explained. It causes an "Invalid node name" error.

Comment: Oh, was not sober while reading this question, sorry for that. Steve is right, answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that there is no good solutions. I will do a export from the old db and import of the data into a new one created with the correct node name.