# Erlang version 18.0 and ejabberd nodename conflict

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I wanted to install latest ejabberd from https://github.com/processone/ejabberd. For this, Erlang/OTP 18 is required. That too, i have manually installed from https://github.com/erlang/otp. Then, i need to start ejabberd server with command `ejabberdctl start`. But there is some error in that.
My mnesia node name is `akash@akash-Latitude-3450` and ejabberd nodename is `akash@localhost`. Due to this, server is not getting started. How to resolve this conflict ?

Log ->

> 2016-01-07 18:38:20.410 [critical] <0.39.0>@ejabberd_app:db_init:125 Node name mismatch: I'm [ejabberd@localhost], the database is owned by ['ejabberd@akash-Latitude-3450']
>
> 2016-01-07 18:38:20.410 [critical] <0.39.0>@ejabberd_app:db_init:127 Either set ERLANG_NODE in ejabberdctl.cfg or change node name in Mnesia
>
> 2016-01-07 18:38:20.410 [error] <0.38.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.38.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: node_name_mismatch in ejabberd_app:db_init/0 line 129 in application_master:init/4 line 134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. name your Erlang node with the name matching your Mnesia database when you start ejabberd. As suggested by error message, it can be changed in var `ERLANG_NODE` in `ejabberdctl.cfg`.
2. Backup Mnesia database by starting the node under old name, do a fresh install and restore your data with node started with the new name.

Comment: Thanks for that.
But how to configure mnesia ?

Comment: @Akash There's [another stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463400/how-to-rename-the-node-running-a-mnesia-database) specifically detailing how to backup Mnesia and restore it with a different node name, if you follow option 2 of Mickaël Rémond's answer.

Comment: Mnesia is using the node name of the Erlang VM. if you are starting ejabberd with ejabberdctl, you can tweak it in ejabberdctl.cfg, as mentioned.